# How can we copy an Amazon WorkSpace image from one AWS account to another?

Tags: amazon-workspaces

I heard we need to create an AWS support ticket for that and that option is not available for 'basic plan'. Kindly share any details if you guys know. Appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

AWS recently added support for this to the AWS CLI tool. There's still no way to do it through the web dashboard. To do it via CLI, follow the steps below.

Using credentials for the source account:

```
aws workspaces describe-workspace-images --region <source-region>
aws workspaces update-workspace-image-permission --image-id <source-image-id> --region <source-region> --shared-account-id <target-account-id> --allow-copy-image
aws workspaces describe-workspace-image-permissions --image-id <source-image-id> --region <source-region>
```

And then with destination account credentials:

```
aws workspaces describe-workspace-images --image-ids <source-image-id> --region <source-region> --image-type SHARED
aws workspaces copy-workspace-image --source-image-id <source-image-id> --source-region <source-region> --name <new-image-name> --region <source-region>
```

Where `<source-region>` is e.g. `us-east-1`.

The copy will take some time, during which the image state will be `PENDING`. I just did this today and it took maybe 15 minutes.

Comment: OP asked for how to copy between accounts - this can only copy images between regions within one account.

Comment: No, it copies between accounts. I'm not sure how I can edit it to make it more clear. I specifically state that you need to change credentials between the command sets, and as you can see from the `--shared-account-id` parameter, you specify a second account to share to. I'd appreciate it if you would revert your downvote. In fact I just came back here to my own response because I'm about to do this exact thing again.

Comment: Can also confirm that the above commands can be used to copy workspace images between accounts without involving AWS Support

Answer (score 0):

You need to reach out to AWS Support for that.